# Does one only need to look at torus invariant curves to calculate the Seshadri constant for a point of a toric variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, birational-geometry, toric-varieties

If $ X $ is an irreducible projective variety, $ L $ is a Nef divisor on $ X $, $ x $ is a point of $ X $, and $ \pi: \operatorname{Bl}_{x}(X) \to X $ is the natural projection morphism, then the Seshadri constant $ \epsilon(L,x) $ is the maximum real number $ \epsilon $ such that $ \pi^{\ast}(L)-\epsilon E $ is Nef.

Proposition 5.1.5 of Robert Lazasfeld's book **Positivity in Algebraic Geometry** states that
\begin{equation*}
\epsilon(L,x) = \min_{x \in C \subseteq X} \frac{L \cdot C}{\operatorname{mult}_{x}(C)}
\end{equation*}
where $ C $ is a reduced, irreducible curve of $ X $ passing through $ x $.

Theorem 6.3.12 of David Cox, John Little, and Hal Schenck's book **Toric Varieties** says: Let $ D $ be a Cartier divisor on a toric variety $ X_{\Sigma} $ whose fan $ \Sigma $ has convex support of full dimension.  The following are equivalent: a) $ D $ is basepoint free, b) $ D $ is Nef, c) $ D \cdot C \ge 0 $ for all torus-invariant, irreducible, complete curves $ C \subseteq X $.  This book works entirely in characteristic zero, so one may need to add reducedness to the list of assumptions in positive characteristic.

The equivalence of b) and c) makes me think that if $ X_{\Sigma} $ is a toric variety whose fan $ \Sigma $ has convex support of full dimension, then it might be the case that one only needs to consider complete, reduced, irreducible, torus invariant curves passing through $ x $ in computing the Seshadri constant $ \epsilon(L,x) $.

If $ X $ is equal to $ X_{\Sigma} $, where $ \Sigma $ is a toric variety whose fan $ \Sigma $ has convex support of full dimension, $ L $ is a Nef divisor on $ X_{\Sigma} $, and $ x \in X_{\Sigma} $ is a point, then let us define $ \epsilon_{T}(L,x) $ to be the $ \min_{x \in C \subseteq X} \frac{L \cdot C}{\operatorname{mult}_{x}(C)} $ where the minimum is taken over complete, reduced, irreducible, torus invariant curves passing through $ x $.  Does anyone know a result showing that $ \epsilon_{T}(L,x) = \epsilon(L,x) $, or a counterexample where $ \epsilon_{T}(L,x) >\epsilon(L,x) $?  If a counterexample exists, does one still exist if we restrict ourselves to projective, toric surfaces?